Power series representation of $1/(2+x)$
Why the power series representation of $\frac{1}{2+x}$ is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}} x^n$$
and not
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1-x)^n$$
based on $\frac{1}{1-x}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ and $\frac{1}{1-(-1-x)}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1-x)^n$

Around which point are you expanding?

The first one is valid for $|x|<2$ and the second one for $|1+x|<1$. There is no expansion valid for all real values of $x$.

It just depends on the value of $x$. You have to make sure that your power is less than $1$ in absolute value.

There is no such thing as the power series representation of a function. What happens is that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}x^n$ is the power series representation of $\dfrac1{2+x}$ on the interval $(-2,2)$, whereas $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1-x)^n\left(=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(x+1)^n\right)$ is the power series representation of that same function on the interval $(-2,0)$.

They are both representations of the same function on $(-2,0)$.  So too is $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n+1}}(x-1)^n$.

Uh, in general,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac {1}{a + x}
& = \frac {1}{\left( a + b \right) - \left( - 1 \right) \left( x - b \right)} \\
& = \frac {1}{a + b} \bigg[ 1 - \frac {x - b}{a + b} + {\bigg( \frac {x - b}{a + b} \bigg)}^{2} - {\bigg( \frac {x - b}{a + b} \bigg)}^{3} + \cdots \bigg]
\end{align}
$$
for $b - \left| a + b \right| < x < b + \left| a + b \right|$. In your case $a = 2$. What you showed are two special series, one for $b = 0$ and the other for $b = - 1$.
